# EWS - additional text to an attendee

Tags: exchangewebservices

When I invite an attendee to an appointment which I just created using EWS API ,

I want to send extra text/information only to the attendee I'm about to invite ,

(every attendee will have different text )

Is this possible?

If it's not possible ,my workaround , ( only in my head for the moment) is when I add an attendee to an appointment, EWS won't send notification email about it , and instead, I will send manually email with extra information ,

```
// adding an attendee to a appointment  , without sending him notification/invitation
appointment.OptionalAttendees.Add("some1@domain.com");
appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```

but then the question which pop up is "How I reference the appointment I'v just created to the new email I wanna send? " which I couldn't find how to do

Thanks !

Comment: If you create the appointment and then add attendees one by one, tailoring the text and sending the update only to the new attendee each time, does that do the trick?

Comment: what do you mean by " tailoring the text" ? there is "text" which is attached to the appointment - location , time etc`. this is global text ,(every attende can see of course ) I need "private" text for each attendee

Comment: Just wondering if something like this would work: Create the appointment, with no invitees yet. Then add attendee 1, and append private text applicable to attendee 1. Send with update only to attendee 1. Now, add attendee 2, and change the private text to something applicable only to attendee 2. Send with update only to attendee 2. At this point, Attendee 1 has the appointment with "private text", as does Attendee 2, with different "private text". This isn't going to survive post-creation updates, but worth a thought?

Comment: I do create an appointment without attendee and then I invite person by person. Changing the appointment info  for each person is not a solution in my opinion , because its global text and not private text. When I change it , everyone will see it.. the only option for me to send extra data is to send extra email

Comment: Fair enough. If you need a direct reference to the appointment in the extra email you're sending each invitee, perhaps forward it as an attachment in that email?

Comment: my second question was how I do what you'r telling me to do :)  I do have an Appointment object ( EWS object ) but the question is not to convert it to ICS file or "link" it somehow into a new email ... that's the big question :)